# How share images/videos in custom folders using ContentResolver/ or other way in Android ? Getting FileUriExposedException Exception

Tags: android, android-gallery, mediastore, android-contentresolver, android-sharing

I have a custom folder in the Pictures directory, like this `Pictures/MyFolder`. It has images in MyFolder. Here is how to share the images using ContentResolver on `MyFolder` only. Or is any alternative ways to share the image. It is on android 11.

I queried images using the following snippets

```
  String[] projection = new String[]{
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN};
        Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(images,
                projection, // Which
                // columns
                // to return
                null, // Which rows to return (all rows)
                null, // Selection arguments (none)
                orderBy + " DESC" // Ordering
        );

 int bucketColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
            int dateColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN);
            do {
                bucket = cur.getString(bucketColumn);
                if (bucket.equals(context.getString(R.string.app_name))) {
                    date = cur.getString(dateColumn);
                 
                    imagePath = listImageByFolder.get(bucket);
                    if (imagePath == null) {
                        imagePath = new ArrayList<String>();
                    }
                    imagePath.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)));

                    Uri x = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA))));
                    listImageByFolder.put(bucket, imagePath);
                } ;
            } while (cur.moveToNext());
```

While I try to share the image, Getting `android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/WhatsTouch/1628090801008.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()` exception. Is any way to correct it or is any alternative way?

Comment: Do away with imagePath and use Uri x directly.

Comment: So make an array list for uries. Share the uries.

Comment: Thanks for reply @blackapps, How to get assest uri by using Cursor ?. I tried this `new File(imagePath).getUri()` it is not working... Is any way to get URI directly?

Comment: Determine column ._ID. Then Uri with appended id.

Comment: is it internal uri or external uri... or is any constant avialable ? @blackapps

Comment: Use the same collection uri as used for the query.

Comment: Can you give some code @blackapps

Comment: There is not more then collection uri, id and uri with appended id.